# Does the percentage of fluctuation remain the same regardless of the value in all wallets?

Tags: wallet, value

This was initially going to reference this question [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/31964/does-the-value-of-my-bitcoin-fluctuate-automatically)

I, as well, have $10 bitcoin in my wallet, I notice the value does fluctuate. However, will the value fluctuate the same in a $100 wallet, as if it were $10?

In other words, my $10 is now $1**1.72**, does that mean the value of a $100 wallet will be $10**1.72**, or will the value be much higher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [one of the answers](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/31965/516) for the question you referenced, it does depend on how you express value.

Your example of $10 increasing to $11.72 is an increase in value of 17.2%

If you ignored any transaction fees, and any effects of market depth, then it would be reasonable to assume that $100 with the same percentage increase of 17.2% would become worth $117.20.

If wallet software took into account the cost of transaction fees, then a higher balance may justify a bigger percentage increase, based on the anticipated transaction fees for spending the funds.

Comment: You rock, that cleared up any other questions I may have!

Answer (score 0):

if your bitcoin equivalent value of 10$ became 11.72$, then 100$ will be 10 times the value - at 117.20 (not 101.72 - I assume this was just a typo).

Comment: I initially edited the question, but then reverted it in case it's not a typo